# Solr lowercase doesnt work

Tags: solr

I am trying to implement case-insensitive search to my `title` and `content`
 fields, however to no avail. I have tried the following methods:

Adding `<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />` to '`text_general`' field type in `schema.xml / managed-schema.xml`, to both 'index' and 'analyze' tokenizers.

[image]

My title and content field each will be of '`text_general`' type.
[image]

I tried searching the following:

- `*abc*` : No results of 'ABC' appears
- `*ABC*` : Only results with 'ABC' appears.

This clearly shows that lowercase filters are not working. Also pasted below is the debug results of the first query.

[image]

Also below is the screenshot of the title field when analyzing a sample text. Output seems ok, but search does not work as per expected. Is this a search query issue?

[image]

Thanks for any help in advanced!

Comment: If you alter the existing schema then you have to reindex

Comment: @AshrafulIslam hi, yeah reindexed and restarted solr instance. I even re-created new cores to test this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't clearly show that the lowercase filtering doesn't work - what you're experiencing is that [*most filters or tokenizers* aren't applied when you're doing a wildcard search](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultitermQueryAnalysis) (since they really can't be applied cleanly for a wildcard search where they don't have the whole term to work with).

The solution is, if you want to perform a wildcarded, lowercased search, is to perform the lowercasing or processing of the field before actually indexing it, and using only a tokenizer to split the text as necessary (where `LowercaseTokenizer` seems to be [the only one that is a MultiTermAwareComponent](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/class-use/MultiTermAwareComponent.html)). Otherwise, if you don't want to perform any tokenization or splitting of the string, use a `string` field.

You can do this either in your own code that sends content to Solr or [in an update processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors).